# Getting an error when using Stripes payment process example

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm using the code example from Stripe's documentation [located here](https://gist.github.com/briancollins/6365455#file-stripetutorialpage-html-L70). But, when this is processed `$form.get(0).submit();` I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement>
is not a function
```

My code is below:

```
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    console.log(token);
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();    **//Error happens here**
  }
};

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('#payment-button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Paul, I've hit the same problem myself, just wondering if you found a solution?

Comment: @snlan - Sorry, no. I ended up doing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line you're getting the error, try this instead:

```
jQuery($form.get(0)).submit();
```

Your problem is that you're getting the first HTML element, but in order to call "submit" on that, you need to wrap it with jQuery.

Comment: Isn't that because you're resubmitting the form? I don't quite understand your logic, but it looks like you wrote an infinite loop. My point being: your initial question is now solved. Now you may need to reexamine your logic.

Comment: It's coming from Stripe's docs. It's a code example I found on their site. It's inserting the token and resubmitting the form. It shouldn't be looping

Comment: I don't know anything about Stripe, but the code you posted is an infinite loop. On submit, you invoke a handler. In the handler, you invoke submit. Etc, etc, etc.